# Groupby - How to apply result of logic check to all rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a set that looks like this:

```
In [127]: df
Out[127]: 
   ID                Date regular_entry
0   1 2014-01-31 12:13:14          True
1   2 2014-02-28 12:13:14         False
2   1 2014-03-31 12:13:14          True
3   1 2014-04-30 12:13:14          True
4   2 2014-05-31 12:13:14         False
5   2 2014-06-30 12:13:14          True
6   3 2014-07-31 12:13:14         False
7   3 2014-08-31 12:13:14          True
8   3 2014-09-30 12:13:14         False
9   1 2014-10-31 12:13:14          True
```

I need to find whether there are any rows, such that `'regular_entry' == False`, for each of the groups (if grouped by `'ID'`).

I am using [`pandas.Series.all()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) and `transform()` to achieve this - as shown below - and it works great:

```
In [134]: df['ever_irregular'] = df.groupby('ID')['regular_entry'].transform(lambda x: False if x.all() else True )

In [135]: df
Out[135]: 
   ID                Date regular_entry ever_irregular
0   1 2014-01-31 12:13:14          True          False
1   2 2014-02-28 12:13:14         False           True
2   1 2014-03-31 12:13:14          True          False
3   1 2014-04-30 12:13:14          True          False
4   2 2014-05-31 12:13:14         False           True
5   2 2014-06-30 12:13:14          True           True
6   3 2014-07-31 12:13:14         False           True
7   3 2014-08-31 12:13:14          True           True
8   3 2014-09-30 12:13:14         False           True
9   1 2014-10-31 12:13:14          True          False
```

Now, I also need to find whether the last entry for each group (if grouped by `'ID'` and taking the values of `'Date'` in mind) had `'regular_entry' == False`

I know I can get the last entry per group like this:

```
In [138]: df.sort_values(by='Date').groupby('ID').nth(-1)['regular_entry']
Out[138]: 
ID
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: regular_entry, dtype: bool
```

And I have by now figured out that I can try to join the two like this:

```
In [152]: df_new = pd.DataFrame(latest_row_regular).rename(columns={'regular_entry':'latest_regular'})

In [155]: pd.merge(df, df_new, left_on='ID', right_index=True).sort_values(by='Date')
Out[155]: 
   ID                Date regular_entry ever_irregular latest_regular
0   1 2014-01-31 12:13:14          True          False           True
1   2 2014-02-28 12:13:14         False           True           True
2   1 2014-03-31 12:13:14          True          False           True
3   1 2014-04-30 12:13:14          True          False           True
4   2 2014-05-31 12:13:14         False           True           True
5   2 2014-06-30 12:13:14          True           True           True
6   3 2014-07-31 12:13:14         False           True          False
7   3 2014-08-31 12:13:14          True           True          False
8   3 2014-09-30 12:13:14         False           True          False
9   1 2014-10-31 12:13:14          True          False           True
```

This seems to be working fine, however, it does seem like the long way round. Is there some easier/faster way to get the values for each of the groups (as grouped after `groupby()`) and apply directly instead of following all the intermediate steps?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
df['latest_regular'] = df.groupby('ID')['regular_entry'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])
print df
   ID                Date regular_entry latest_regular
0   1 2014-01-31 12:13:14          True           True
1   2 2014-02-28 12:13:14         False           True
2   1 2014-03-31 12:13:14          True           True
3   1 2014-04-30 12:13:14          True           True
4   2 2014-05-31 12:13:14         False           True
5   2 2014-06-30 12:13:14          True           True
6   3 2014-07-31 12:13:14         False          False
7   3 2014-08-31 12:13:14          True          False
8   3 2014-09-30 12:13:14         False          False
9   1 2014-10-31 12:13:14          True           True
```

I think for testing is the best use custom function with `print` instaed of lambda:

```
def f(x):
    print x
    print x.iloc[-1]
    return x.iloc[-1]


df['latest_regular'] = df.groupby('ID')['regular_entry'].transform(f)
print df
```

And after testing use lambda function.

Comment: That seems to produce expected result, thanks! How is it that `x.iloc[-1]` fetches the last element in the `['regular_entry']` series though, is `x` not an element of the Series?

Comment: using `print()` I see that `x` is in fact a `pd.Series`, the subset of  `['regular_entry']` that makes sense for each group in this case. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same `.transform` call in the following way:

```
df['latest_regular'] = (df.groupby('ID')['regular_entry']
                        .transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]))
```

---

Working example:

```
df['last_regular'] = df.groupby('ID')['regular_entry'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])

17:41:18 [26]: df
Out[26]:
   ID regular_entry last_regular
0   1          True         True
1   2         False         True
2   1          True         True
3   1          True         True
4   2         False         True
5   2          True         True
6   3         False        False
7   3          True        False
8   3         False        False
9   1          True         True
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, I get `TypeError: last() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'` and when I try with `offset` I get `NotImplementedError: 'last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index`

Comment: @Thanos Perhaps `[-1]` instead of `.last()`?

Comment: This doesn't work either, I believe `x` is an element in this case, I don't think `x[-1]` makes sense here. In any case, it gives `KeyError`.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort, this solution works great.